# Dice and chance of three sixes

Tags: probability

We have 3 normal dices and a fake one who has on all sides the number 6.Randomly we put one away from the 4 dices and then we throw the other 3 dices.What is the probability of getting three sixes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prob of putting the fake aside is $\frac{1}{4}$.  If so prob of 3 sixes $=\frac{1}{6}^3$

Prob of putting a good die aside is $\frac{3}{4}$.  In that case prob of 3 sixes $=\frac{1}{6}^2$.

Overall prob $=\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{6}^3+\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{6}^2=\frac{19}{864}$.